# Select operations from tables using JOINS in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have three sql tables called financetrail , fooperson and idDog .All of them have the column `idFoo` :

I have created the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCustomerFinance] @idFinanceType INT 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT idCustomer
FROM financetrail
where idFinanceType = @idFinanceType ;
END

GO
```

so i can dynamically choose customers of a certain finance type.

The above procedure generates a table along these lines:

[image: getCustomerFinance Stored Procedure result table]

I also have this query

```
SELECT firstName , lastName
FROM IdDog RIGHT JOIN fooPerson 
ON IdDog.idFoo = fooPerson.idFoo WHERE IdDog.idIdDog IS NULL;
```

The result gives me all customers who don't have a dog in the dog table.

#### What i want to do ?

I want to create a stored procedure that would give me all the customers who don't have a valid idCard(query above) and are of a certain riskType defined from the stored procedure above .

What i have tried  ?

I have tried doing the following :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getMissingDogs] 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @financeFilterTable table ( idCustomer INT)
INSERT INTO @financeFilterTable
EXEC getCustomerRisk 3
SELECT * FROM @financeFilterTable

SELECT firstName , lastName
FROM IdCard RIGHT JOIN FooPerson 
ON IdCard.idCustomer = FooPerson.idFoo WHERE IdDog.idIdDog IS       NULL;
END
```

and i get the following results :

[image: getMissingDogs result table]

In the current result set i have two tables . One table giving Customer ids for customers of a certain risk type and the second table giving the customers who don't have an idCard .

I want to find all customers who fulfill both criteria (have a certain risk type and not have an idCard ) in one table 
Is that possible ?

Comment: It is possible but it is not at all clear what you want for output here. You would have to either modify your queries to have the columns or deal with NULLs for the "other" type.

Comment: I would suggest to join @riskFilterTable with your second query. The first select ("SELECT * FROM @riskFilterTable") should be removed...

Comment: Please see the edits if it wasn't clear about what i want to achieve .

Comment: I smell OUTER APPLY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I fully understand your requirement. Would it be possible please to post some sample data and expected query results?

Maybe the stored procecure below works for you?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getMissingDogs] 
@idFinanceType INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @financeFilterTable table ( idCustomer INT)
INSERT INTO @financeFilterTable
EXEC getCustomerRisk @idFinanceType

SELECT firstName , lastName
FROM IdCard RIGHT JOIN FooPerson ON IdCard.idCustomer = FooPerson.idFoo
INNER JOIN @financeFilterTable AS RiskType ON RiskType.idCustomer = IdCard.idCustomer
WHERE IdDog.idIdDog IS       NULL;
END
```